# Protractor won't run chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, protractor

Protractor was running fine but suddenley won't run chrome anymore. This is mye current configuration:

```
exports.config = {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1384/#/',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['./tests/e2e/*.js'],
    multiCapabilities: [{
      //'browserName': 'firefox',
      'browserName': 'chrome',
    }, 
    ],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
      showColors: true
    }
  }
```

I am running latest of all the related dependencies:

- protractor : `"protractor": "^5.2.0",`
- chromedriver:  `2.33.506092`
- webdriver:  `selenium standalone version available: 3.7.1 [last]`

when I run `webdriver-manager start` eveything runs fine, and then running `protractor conf.js` gives the following output in the window running the selenium server:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506092 Only local connections are allowed.
```

The terminal windows running the protractor config, gives the following errros:

```
E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```

I have already tried reinstalling protractor and updating the chromedriver. Running the tests work fine in firefox with the exact same configurations.

I am also running tests with karma, and karma runs fine in a chrome browser window.

Comment: may be incompatibility between chrome and chrome driver versions?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I'm running Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit), and the driver I'm running should also be the latest

Answer (score 0):

Add **directConnect: true** to your config file. It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

this would be your conf file

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
  },

  // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine',
  baseUrl: "YOUR URL",

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['../Tests/test.js'],


  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  },
    };
```

you don't need to give below dependencies because chrome get launched from conf file only

- chromedriver: 2.33.506092
- webdriver: selenium standalone version available: 3.7.1 [last]

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar issue. Try updating chrome which should fetch the new compatible chrome driver.